# Database: new table or new field for order attributes

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

Current table schema:

```
User
  - id
  - default_handling_fee(integer, null=True)

Order
  - id
  - buyer(user_id)
  - order_handling_fee(integer, null=True)
```

We now want to add a second type of fee that can apply to orders. Some rules:

1. Fees apply to < 10% of orders.
2. An order can have 0, either, or both fees.
3. Every time order info is displayed to users, we need to
   highlight fees and show the types of fees.
4. Fees must be editable on an order-by-order basis.
5. We may add additional fees going forward.
6. The db is currently pretty small (a few thousand rows) and unlikely
   to grow beyond 100k in the next few years.

I can see two options:

A: Add a new field on order and one on user:

```
User
  - id
  - default_handling_fee(integer, null=True)
  - default_processing_fee(integer, null=True)

Order
  - id
  - buyer(user_id)
  - order_handling_fee(integer, null=True) 
  - order_processing_fee(integer, null=True)
```

or B, add a new 'fees table':

```
User
  - id

Order
  - id
  - buyer(user_id)
  - order_fees(many_to_many_field to OrderFees)

OrderFees
  - id
  - buyer(user_id)
  - price(integer)
  - fee_type(choices=['handling', 'processing'])
  - is_default_value(boolean)
```

If a user creates an order and applies one or both of the fees, in option B (new table), we would first look for existing fees that match the user and the price. If that combination exists, we would add it to the `order_fees` field.  If it did not exist (a new price), we would create a new row and add that row to the `order_fees` field.

I recognize that option A is a lot simpler: no joins when looking up fees, no creating new rows, no stale rows that get created once and never used again.
I see two downsides of A.  For one, it's not extensible. If we add a `gift_wrapping_fee` in a few months, that will mean adding a third field with null on nearly every order, and so on for additional types of order fees.  The second disadvantage is that we have to remember to add checks in-app in every place that order info is displayed.

```
if order.order_processing_fee: 
  show fee
if order.order_handling_fee:
  show fee
```

With option B, it's just

```
for fee in order.order_fees:
  show fee
```

There is much less chance of errors in option B at the cost of at least one additional query per order shown to users.

One additional point: since this is all being done with Django as a backend, we can define methods on the model such that all the price fields are defined in one place.

Which option is better? Is there a third option I haven't considered?

(edited for clarity)

Comment: The second one violates normalization. Don't put `order_fees` in `order`. But have another table where the order's ID is a foreign key, that stores the actual fees in rows for a referenced order. That said for just two fees two columns in the order table are probably the OK solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that if, in a near future, you will need to add new fee types, than the B option is better.

Have you considered a hybrid option of A and B? If i've understand the problem,  you don't have only an order fee but a default fee for the users too.

You can have a Fee table:

```
Fees
-id
-type(choices=[your fee type list])
-price
...(other attributes)
```

And then you can have two many to many relation, one for the Order

```
Order 
-id
-buyer(user)
-order_fees(many to many)
```

And a second for the user

```
User
-id
-default_fees(many to many)
```

Comment: That's an interesting hybrid idea.  With the `user.default_fees` design, when a user changes their default processing fee price, for example, we would have to check for a processing fee in the current `default_fees` field and remove it, if present, before adding the newly created fee.  That's not a terrible task, but it is another layer of management.

Comment: hmm...  well you can add a new processing fee then and change the relationship between fees and user. Maybe a flag in the fees table ( in ex. active / inactive) will help,  and adding this you can have a fees history for the user.